# Image next to a paragraph inside a box

Tags: html, css, position

I have recently tried to code a box, contains an image on the left side and next to it an header & paragraph under right like this:

http://gyazo.com/c5165fa45c32f69499768ba95d815328

This is what i have done:

```
       <div class="span4">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="img/share.png" class="image_margin"/>
                <span class="box_title">SHARE</span>
                <span id="texting">Upload files straight from you hard disc. Up to 600MB per file upload! the more you earn the more file storage you get.</span>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    background-image: url("../img/box.png");
    width: 305px;
    height: 117px;
}
#texting {
font-size: 14px;
}

.image_margin{
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.box_title{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #8d8d8d;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is the result:

http://gyazo.com/f600c42f86b51e52de436631fc96656d

Why the text gets out of the box yet its inside the class of the box ?
What have I done wrong? how do I align the title + paragraph like in the first image in CSS so it fits on all screens?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `align="left"` in `img` tag.

```
<img src="img/share.png" class="image_margin" align="left"/>
```

Hope this will help